# Automatizar un script en wifislax

Tags: linux

No estoy seguro de qué esto vaya aquí, en este foro, si se salta alguna norma, por favor disculpen.

Uso wifislax para comprobar la seguridad de mi red y de algunos amigos, lo hago a nivel amateur y tengo poco idea, así que cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Quería saber si hay alguna forma de lanzar un programa, "un ataque", que se automatice.

Siempre lanzo el mismo ataque, el linset, o el reaven y siempre escojo las mismas opciones. ¿Habría alguna forma de automatiar el progreso?

¿Con algún tipo de lenguaje, quizás?

Muchas gracias ^^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al margen de para que lo vayas a usar, puedes crear un script de bash para ejecutar varios comandos.

Crea un fichero "miscript.sh" que contenga esto

```
#!/bin/bash
comando1
comando2
comando3
```

En tu caso irías poniendo cada comando que utilices con sus parámetros.

Si los pones uno debajo de otro, se ejecutarán en secuencia, cuando acabe uno se ejecutará el siguiente.

Si necesitas que los comandos se ejecuten en cadena de forma que un comando solo se ejecute si el anterior ha tenido éxito, lo puedes hacer así:

```
#!/bin/bash
comando1 && comando2 && comando3
```

De esta forma, si falla el comando 2, el comando 3 no se ejecutará y si comando1 falla, comando2 y comando 3 no se ejecutarán.

Se entiende que un comando falla, si el programa devuelve un código de error distinto de 0. Se entiende como éxito si devuelve el código de error 0. Esto lo puedes consultar viendo la página del manual del comando que estés usando. Lo puedes ver con

```
man comando
```

Para salir pulsa "q".

Una vez tengas tu script, le tienes que dar permisos de ejecución con

```
chmod +x miscript.sh
```

Y después lo puedes ejecutar (acuérdate del punto barra delante)

```
./miscript.sh
```

Espero que te sirva, y lo uses para hacer el bien ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Tengo muy poca experiencia con bash y con los comando de linset, a ver si consigo hacerlo.

(Cualquier ayuda extra, es bienvenida).

Y no te preocupes, jajaj, lo peor que haré con él, será cobrar para comprobar la seguridad, solo eso, jajaja.